# WHERE statement in block where using UNION ALL between them? GROUP BY error

Tags: sql

Have some trouble with this error in my code.

```
Expected tokens [EOF]. Found token [GROUP] (Line: 61, Column: 1)
```

All I'm doing is a query on union all between statements. My code looks something like this.

```
Select vehicles,
SUM(passengers) 
FROM 

(
  SELECT 
  "Toyota" As vehicles,
      count(distinct uid) As passengers
        FROM vehicle_table_1
        WHERE timestamp > '2018-12-31 23:59:59' AND model in ('Land Cruiser','C-HR')

UNION ALL

(SELECT
  "Land Rover" As vehicles,
     COUNT (DISTINCT uid) As passengers
        FROM vehicle_table_2
        WHERE timestamp > '2018-12-31 23:59:59') 

UNION ALL

(SELECT 
  "Jeep" As vehicles,
    count(distinct uid) As passengers
      FROM  vehicle_table_3
      WHERE submitted_timestamp > '2018-12-31 23:59:59')

GROUP BY 1
```

Why am I getting this group by error? Is is not possible to have where statements within these blocks? Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need one GROUP BY for each SELECT with COUNT().

Comment: Tip of today: have one common vehicle_table - for all brands.

Comment: You have 1 `(` more than  `)`

Comment: Its fake table names and variables lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the union in a subquery of its own:

```
Select  vehicles,
        SUM(passengers) 
FROM    (
         SELECT "Toyota" As vehicles,
                count(distinct uid) As passengers
         FROM   vehicle_table_1
         WHERE  timestamp > '2018-12-31 23:59:59' AND model in ('Land Cruiser','C-HR')

        UNION ALL

        SELECT   "Land Rover" As vehicles,
                 COUNT (DISTINCT uid) As passengers
        FROM     vehicle_table_2
        WHERE    timestamp > '2018-12-31 23:59:59'

        UNION ALL

        SELECT "Jeep" As vehicles,
               count(distinct uid) As passengers
        FROM   vehicle_table_3
        WHERE  submitted_timestamp > '2018-12-31 23:59:59'
    ) AS sel

GROUP BY vehicles
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `GROUP BY`.  Your subqueries are already separate rows.  You can also simplify the date comparisons:

```
select 'Toyota' As vehicles,
       count(distinct uid) as passengers
from vehicle_table_1
where timestamp >= '2019-01-01' and
      model in ('Land Cruiser', 'C-HR')
union all
select 'Land Rover' As vehicles,
       count(distinct uid) As passengers
from vehicle_table_2
where timestamp >= '2019-01-01'
union all
select 'Jeep' As vehicles,
       count(distinct uid) As passengers
from vehicle_table_3
where submitted_timestamp > '2019-01-01';
```

If you want to control the ordering of the final result set, then use `order by vehicles`.